# thinning algorithm and post processing for binary images

Tags: python, image-processing, post-processing

I have pictures of networks, and my goal is to process the images in order to extract the skeleton of the network.

My approach lies in two steps :

1) Going from grayscale image to binary image (Using local thresholding or Otsu method, and then a medianfilter (python function medfilt)

2) Using thinning algorithms in order to extract the skeleton of the network.

[image: original image]
[image: Binary image]

[image: Skeleton]

Considering the quality of the first image, I'm pretty sure I can do a lot better than that. I thus have two question :

1) Taking the last image, how would you remove all the small lines perpendendicular to the ridges, and the small gaps, that are artefacts ?

2) What algorithm would you actually advise me to use for these two steps ?

Comment: Your thinning result is wrong, it doesn't have the correct connexity, or you downsampled the binary image.

Comment: What do you mean by "downsampled the binary image" ?

Comment: You're right. Is there anyway to take this post and simply put it there, or should I repost in this other subforum?

Comment: Yes, there is. It's to flag the post for a moderator attention and request migration. I already did that, but they rejected the flag for some reason... So, I think, it will be better if you just simply repost your question there.